# Extraer múltiplos de 3 de un array existente python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Tengo el siguiente array:

```
arr=np.random.randint(100,500,(20,20))
```

De los valores que me da al imprimir el array, ¿cómo busco los que sean múltiplos de 3 y los coloco en un nuevo array mediante una operación de indexado?

Yo había hecho lo siguiente pero sin ningún resultado.

```
multiplos=if arr[0]%3==0
sl1=arr[np.arange(multiplos)]
print(sl1)
```

Comment: `multiplos = arr[arr % 3 == 0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando tienes un arreglo, como este

```
a = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100])
```

y quieres obtener un nuevo arreglo con el primer, tercer y quinto elemento (por ejemplo), puedes hacerlo usando como indice otro arreglo: [0, 2, 4], así

```
b=a[[0,2,4]]
print(b)
```

produce

```
[10, 30, 50]
```

En lugar de un arreglo de indices numéricos, puedes pasar un arreglo de valores lógicos, con lo que seleccionas los valores que coinciden con `True`. Este arreglo tiene que tener la misma dimensión que el arreglo de valores.

```
a = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100])
b = a[[True, False, True, False, False, True, True, False, True, False]]
print(b)
```

produce

```
[10 30 60 70 90]
```

Puedes aplicar una operación elemento por elemento de una matriz simplemente escribiendo `matriz operador valor`, lo que produce una nueva matriz.

Entonces,

```
arr % 3 == 0
```

genera una matriz conteniendo `True` y `False`, según cada elemento sea o no múltiplo de 3.

```
b = arr % 3 == 0
print(b)
```

produce

```
array([[ True, False, False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False,
        False,  True, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False,
        False,  True],
    ... etc ...
```

por tanto,

```
c = arr[b]
```

produce

```
[273 315 408 159 210 447 135 432 468 216 189 486 351 198 354 273 285 471
 129 327 459 468 126 198 468 201 165 420 333 282 294 177 294 240 213 381
 414 177 201 234 354 339 189 480 195 276 258 429 360 459 435 207 210 324
 171 246 426 459 372 243 321 366 105 348 420 357 345 186 276 372 495 387
 216 267 345 345 243 297 492 435 225 141 204 186 132 357 351 243 108 468
 336 258 462 177 324 321 417 387 147 282 345 159 141 453 333 198 366 426
 273 480 348 495 369 426 201 147 423 339 246 252 360 180 426 186 210 138
 384 435 348 162 360 180 144 375]
```

Tu pregunta se puede responder entonces en una sola línea.

```
multiplos = arr[arr % 3 == 0]
```

Q.E.D.

Comment: Perfecto. Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Exactamente hace lo que pedí.